How to change the background color of a Datatable header using css?
My question is similar to this question, except that I would like to use a css rule in an external css file.

This question is similar to: Background color of DT::datatable in shiny. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

includeCSS()

Based on this other question, I succeeded by using the following css rule :
table.dataTable thead th {
      background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
      color: white !important;
    }

